# Query to get files URL from sharepoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, caml

Is it possible to get a perticular file from sharepoint instead of getting all files at onlce?

In below query when I `queryNode` is empty I am getting all the files but when `queryNode` is commented query I am not getting any file.

What is missing here?

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();         
        XmlNode queryNode = xmlDoc.AppendChild(xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", ""));

        //queryNode.InnerXml = "<Where>" +
        //                    "   <Eq>" +
        //                    "       <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'></FieldRef>" +
        //                    "       <Value Type='File'>" + SomeFileName + "</Value>" +
        //                    "    </Eq>" +
        //                    "</Where>";

        queryNode.InnerText = "";

        XmlDocument xmlDoc1 = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode viewNode = xmlDoc.AppendChild(xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", ""));            
        viewNode.InnerXml = "";  

        XmlDocument xmlDoc2 = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode optionsNode = xmlDoc.AppendChild(xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "QueryOptions", ""));
        optionsNode.InnerText = ""; 

        XmlNode nodeListItems = wsList.GetListItems("Documents",
                                                    "",
                                                    queryNode,
                                                    viewNode,
                                                    "1",
                                                    optionsNode,
                                                    null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will retrieve all items in a list with a filename of "filename" only.

```
var list = web.Lists["ListTitle"];
var fileQuery = new SPQuery();
fileQuery .ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
string strQuery = "<Where>" +
                 "<Eq>" +
                   "<FieldRef Name=\"FileLeafRef\"/>" +
                    "<Value Type=\"Text\">" + fileName + "</Value>" +
                 "</Eq>" +
                "</Where>";
fileQuery .Query = strQuery ;
SPListItemCollection collListItems = list.GetItems(fileQuery );
```

Comment: I can't use the way you have implemented `var fileQuery = new SPQuery();`